# Get related Campaigns On Account

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to add Subgrid on Account entity that would show Campaigns that have this Account record on Marketing list.

There is only a way to do this by showing Campaigns related to Account by responses, but i need to get Campaigns related to Account by common Marketing List.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This isn't easy. I digged this up from my bookmarks https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f677710c-8d75-479d-ac0e-6789e4a239de/use-a-subgrid-to-show-which-campaigns-a-contact-has-been-involved-in?forum=crm never implement it myself though